# how to use "buh-bye" in daily life?

Tags: american-english

How can we use "buh-bye" in daily life? Can we use it just on the phone? any restrictions?

I have seen on the web that it can be used always in informal situations.

Comment: It is informal. I've known people who use it frequently, but to my ear it sounds childish (or like something you would say to a child), even baby talk-ish.

Comment: There was a Saturday Night Live skit that might make using it not a good idea. http://www.hulu.com/watch/291277

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use this phrase? I don't think the average native speaker would use it on a regular basis.

Comment: What are the words I could use instead?

Comment: I say it on occasion, especially on the phone talking to older female relatives, but I wouldn't say its common. Most people would opt for just "bye", "good-bye", "see ya", "see ya later", "talk to you later", etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you were in a formal conversation, say, with a professor or teacher, you wouldn't want to use "buh-bye" when leaving the conversation. The proper thing to say would be goodbye, or bye. Buh-bye is something that should be used informally with friends or relatives.

Someone else had said "bye-bye" is a better alternative to buh-bye; however, I believe that, in practice, they both come off the same way. Buh-bye is what comes out when you're saying bye-bye quickly, and enunciating bye-bye may even make you seem more informal than saying buh-bye. I would imagine saying bye-bye to a little child or baby, not to an adult.

In short, stick to goodbye or bye in more formal conversations and buh-bye in more informal ones.